# IVV, how much did it really go up?

Tags: stocks, etf

I am invested in IVV and was surprised today when I saw the S&P500 and VOO shoot up 0.7% in the morning, while my IVV shares only went up ~0.02%.

The day ended with the S&P 500 up 0.71% and VOO up 0.71%, but IVV it seems to depend who you ask.

On my profile with Schwab, it says I went up 0.08% ($0.24/share).
If I look up the close friday it says it closed at 319.08. Since it closed at 319.32 today, the 0.08% makes sense.

If I look up the symbol in Schwab, it says it went up 0.58% ($1.84/share)
If I look up the previous close here, without looking up a specific date, it says the previous close was 317.4778, which would make sense for the 0.58%.

And then Yahoo reports other numbers entirely. Previous close 315.00, open 319.00, todays close 319.32, and reports 4.32 up (1.37%)

I didn't do any buying or selling any time recently.

Why did I get 0.08% instead of 0.58%?
Why do there seem to be different closing prices for Friday based on who you ask?
Why did IVV, which is supposed to mirror the S&P pretty closely deviate so much from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this is an issue of one web site adjusted the data but other not doing it yet.

Yahoo's current historical data shows the closes for Friday and Monday as $319.08 and $319.32.  That agrees with Schwab.  I would guess that your  Yahoo number of $315.00 for Friday was  bad data by Yahoo at the time that you  looked it up.  That happens occasionally at Yahoo.

The [I Shares](https://www.ishares.com/us/products/239726/ishares-core-sp-500-etf) web site says that IVV went ex-dividend today in the amount of $2.039089 per share.  Because share price is reduced on the ex-dividend date by the exchanges by the exact amount of the dividend, some of your data hasn't yet accounted for that.

Add $2.04 to Friday's  close of $319.32 and you have an unadjusted close of $321.32 which means that IVV was really up $2.28 today.

Your second set of Schwab numbers is adjusted data.  If you add today's increase of $1.84 to their Friday adjusted close of  $317.48, you get $331.32 which now agrees with the other two closes you mentioned.

I think that when everyone adjusts their data in the next few days, they should line up better.